# How do I avoid a click event firing after dragging a gridster.js widget with clickable content?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, gridster

I'm using Gridster (http://gridster.net/) which able to drag the content inside the `li` . In my `li` there is a clickable div.

```
<li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1">
    <a href=' '>
    <div>
       content
    </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

so here is the problem I'm facing, when I stop and release the dragging, it will invoke the click in the div, how can I just dragging the div, but not invoking the click after drag stop&release. I do not want it to redirect to another page after dragging( user drag and release ..since when drag,it need to click the div,meanwhile, the div can be clicked, so when stop&release the drag, it will invoke the click )

```
$(function(){ //DOM Ready

    var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster(
    {
          widget_margins: [5, 5],
        widget_base_dimensions: [128, 130],
        max_size_y: 2,
        max_size_x: 2,
        extra_cols: 6
    }
    ).data('gridster');
    //which i tried but failed
    gridster.draggable.stop(){
        onclick = "false";
    }


//   gridster.resize_widget($('.gridster li').eq(0), 1,1);

});
```

or anyone can give hints about how to invoke or use the function that provided by gridster

> draggable.stop: function(event, ui){} A callback for when dragging stops.

I guess there will be some implementation on here.

initial solution but still not working yet

```
    var gridster ,draggable ;
   $(function () {
        gridster = $(".gridster > ul").find("> li ").click(function(e){
            !draggable && alert(1) //ipad2 ，not show alert
            draggable=0;
            alert(draggable);
            }).end()
            .gridster({widget_margins: [5, 5],
            widget_base_dimensions: [128, 130],min_cols: 10,min_rows: 20
            ,serialize_params: function($w, wgd) {
                return {
                    id: wgd.el[0].id
                    //,col: wgd.col
                    //,row: wgd.row
                };
            }
            ,draggable: {
                start:function(event, ui){ 
                //  alert("hekio);");
                    draggable=1; }
            }
        }).data('gridster');
    //gridster.disable();
//   gridster.resize_widget($('.gridster li').eq(0), 1,1);
         if(!dragged){
            $("a#blue.grid").click(function(){
            window.location = '../yokotachi/category_list.php?category=yokosmart';
        });
            }
    // RESET DRAGGED SINCE CLICK EVENT IS FIRED AFTER drag stop
            dragged = 0
    });
```

Comment: Removed PHP tag, since this is not PHP related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed it with a trigger variable: var dragged = 0
Add the following to your gridster initialization which sets the variable to 1 on drag start:

```
...
    draggable: {
        start: function(event, ui) {

            dragged = 1;
            // DO SEOMETHING
        }
    }
....
```

In your click event on the same object, check:

```
...
    if(!dragged){
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
    // RESET DRAGGED SINCE CLICK EVENT IS FIRED AFTER drag stop
dragged = 0
....
```

Comment: Although that will generally work, it's pretty nasty scattering your state across the app like that. In addition, it scatters this particular concern into all of your click handlers, rather than dealing with it in one place. Finally, it's also possible to skip triggering the click event by alt-tabbing out of your app while you're dragging, at which point the next time you click nothing will happen because the state will be inconsistent. I've posted a better solution - I hope you'll accept that instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that the `click` event is fired *after* the `mouseup` event that is passed to `draggable.stop`.

You therefore need to briefly trap that click event and stop it propagating, then untrap it once you've finished so people can subsequently click on the item.

You can do this like so (**[click for working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g22caks6/15/)**):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Basic event handler to prevent event propagation and clicks
  var preventClick = function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); };
  $(element).gridster({
    draggable: {
      start: function (event, ui) {
        // Stop event from propagating down the tree on the capture phase
        ui.$player[0].addEventListener('click', preventClick, true);
      },
      stop: function (event, ui) {
        var player = ui.$player;
        setTimeout(function () {
          player[0].removeEventListener('click', preventClick, true);
        });
      }
    }
  });
})
```

This is a much better solution than the currently accepted answer, because it avoids having a variable with state being set/checked across multiple components/handlers.

Comment: An excellent answer; certainly a far cleaner solution than the accepted one. Thanks!

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you should try that :

```
var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');
gridster.disable();
```

Comment: it works for some, can i know the reason behind?? 
 gridster.disable is doing ?

Comment: In your example you've used the callback, but there a direct method made to disable the dragable feature.
see the doc ;)
[link](http://gridster.net/#disable_method)

Comment: hmm sorry, there is some miss communicate ,what I want to do is I able to drag, but after I release the drag, I do not want to invoke the click(which it will direct me to other page)

Answer (score 1):

For those that came across this thread looking for a solution in Gridster2 using Angular, the following is based on Alastair Maw's answer but updated to work for Gridster2 by using the initCallBack option.

```
ngOnInit() {
    const preventClick = (e) => { e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); };
    this.gridsterOptions = {
      initCallback: (gridster: GridsterComponentInterface) => {
        gridster.options = {
          draggable: {
            delayStart: 100,
            start: (event, ui) => {
              // Stop event from propagating down the tree on the capture phase
              setTimeout(() => {
                ui.el.addEventListener('click', preventClick, true);
              }, 100);
            },
            stop: (event, ui) => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                ui.el.removeEventListener('click', preventClick, true);
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without digging into the JS, adding `onclick = "return false;"` to your `<a>` tag should stop the click from triggering.

For stopping just the drag, try:

```
gridster.draggable.stop(){
   return false;
}
```

or

```
gridster.draggable.stop(e){
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: wow,thats cool :D any alternative solution that separate js with html? jz curious..

Comment: Hold on, there is some miss communicate...I wishes able to click the div if it is not in dragging mode, but if dragging, I do not want to invoke the click...

Comment: In which case, it would help to see your JS.

Answer (score 0):

There now is a native support to disable the drag and drop operation on Gridster.

`$(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster').disable();`

Comment: The OP doesn't want to disable drag and drop, he just wants the drop to not click.