# Prevent click event when drag with jquery gridster

Tags: jquery, gridster

I am using gridster [gridster.net](http://gridster.net/) for some draggable items. Those items are also clickable. When there is a click, it expands. But problem is that when I drag an item, it also fire a click event and the item expands after dropping. How can I prevent that?

Here is my jquery code example:

```
$(document).on('click touchend', '.gridster li.gs-closed p', function() {
    var clickedItem = $(this);
    var parent = clickedItem.parent('li');
    gridster.resize_widget(parent, 1,4);
    parent.removeClass('gs-closed').addClass('gs-opened');
});

$(document).on('dblclick touchend', '.gridster li.gs-opened p', function() {
    var clickedItem = $(this);
    var parent = clickedItem.parent('li');
    gridster.resize_widget(parent, 1, 1);
    parent.removeClass('gs-opened').addClass('gs-closed');
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [gridster ,do not invoke the click action for the div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301026/gridster-do-not-invoke-the-click-action-for-the-div)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've found for this comes from Alastair Maw. Here is a link to the SO page where the solution comes from. 
[How do I avoid a click event firing after dragging a gridster.js widget with clickable content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301026/how-do-i-avoid-a-click-event-firing-after-dragging-a-gridster-js-widget-with-cli)

Sadly it was not selected as the preferred answer, but just scroll down to find it.

Here is the completed script block working for me, which takes Alastair's solution.

```
<script>
    function pageLoad() {

        var preventClick = function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); };

        $(".gridster ul").gridster({
            widget_margins: [10, 10],
            widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140], 

            draggable: {
                start: function (event, ui) {
                    // Stop event from propagating down the tree on the capture phase
                    ui.$player[0].addEventListener('click', preventClick, true);
                },
                stop: function (event, ui) {
                    var player = ui.$player;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        player[0].removeEventListener('click', preventClick, true);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this worked for me:
Original answer: [How do I avoid a click event firing after dragging a gridster.js widget with clickable content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301026/gridster-do-not-invoke-the-click-action-for-the-div)

```
...
    draggable: {
        start: function(event, ui) {

            dragged = 1;
            // DO SEOMETHING
        }
    }
....
```

Then

```
...
    if(!dragged){
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
    // RESET DRAGGED SINCE CLICK EVENT IS FIRED AFTER drag stop
dragged = 0
....
```